# Are you allowed to not block and let the damage slip through?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Is it allowed for you to not defend with any creatures at all when the opponent is attacking (even if you have untapped creatures) and take the damage yourself?

For example, I have a sliver deck and I want to build up on slivers to take down my opponent, but my opponent attacks me and the creature she uses is capable of taking out my sliver. Am I allowed to ignore that creature and not assign defenders to defend the damage and just take the damage myself?

Answer (score 10):

**You are not forced to block attacking creatures.**

There are certain creature abilities that force you to block, but generally, you can leave attacking creatures unblocked, and they will deal their damage to you instead of your creatures. I suggest you read the [Basic rulebook](https://www.wizards.com/magic/rules/EN_MTGM11_Rulebook_LR_Web.pdf):

> Your opponent chooses which of his or her creatures will
>   block. Tapped creatures can’t be declared as blockers.
>   For blocking, it doesn’t matter how long the creature has
>   been on the battlefi eld. Each creature can block only one
>   attacker, but multiple blockers can gang up on a single
>   attacking creature. If that happens, the attacking player
>   orders the blockers to show which is fi rst in line for
>   damage, which is second, and so on. **Creatures don’t have
>   to block.**